# Not able to pull PHP information in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Index.php →

```
    <form>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn">Click me I am Neo Anderson</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $.post("ajax.php",function(response){
                // alert(response);
                var message = $("#message").val();
                message.html(response);         
            })
            .fail(function(error){
                alert(error.StatusText);
            })
        })      
    })      
</script>
```

And ajax.php →

```
    <?php 
echo "The ajax post is working";
```

Issue: I am unable to get the print material from ajax.php file in my ajax request. where am I faltering?

Comment: you're making a post request, you should make a get request to fetch the data

Comment: @RohitAmbre I assume that the author has shortened the code sample and there will be more operations in the ajax.php file. The structure of the form (name field commented out) suggests that there will be some kind of save operation there. So post request is probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
var message = $("#message").val();
```

Replace that line of code with this:

```
var message = $("#message");
```

You don't want to get a value of the #message div so don't use `val()` method.

Answer (score 1):

$("#message").html(response);

```
    //or
```

var message = $(“#message”);

message.html(response);

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        let message = $("#message").val();
        $.post("ajax.php",{
         msg: message
        },
        function(response){
            // alert(response);
            message.html(response);         
        },"json")
    })      
})
```

Essayer ceci pour le JavaScript.
Et pour le fichier ajax.php essayer ceci:

```
<?php 
echo json_encode("The ajax post is working");
```

Comment: I was interested in doing it w/o JSON.